# srcset : trouble getting it right

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hello I want to score a perfect 100 on google page speed. That's why I need to implement srcset for mobile and desktop. but for some reason I'm having a hard time getting this right. I have 2 images: one is 1920 wide and the other is 1024 wide. the fallback image is the big one. for small screens I will use the 1024 image. what should my srcset look like?

```
<img class="h-56 w-full object-cover sm:h-72 md:h-96 lg:w-full lg:h-full"
      srcset="../assets/img/splash-small.jpg 1024w, ../assets/img/splash.jpg 1920w"
      sizes="(max-width: 800px) ??????, ?????"
      src="../assets/img/splash.jpg"
      alt="poker game picture">
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it could look something like this:

```
<img class="h-56 w-full object-cover sm:h-72 md:h-96 lg:w-full lg:h-full"
     srcset="../assets/img/splash-small.jpg 1024w, 
             ../assets/img/splash.jpg 1920w"
     sizes="(min-width: 800px) 1920px,
            100vw"
     src="../assets/img/splash.jpg"
     alt="poker game picture">
```

If the width is maximum of 1024px (you could also keep it at 800px) it would serve the smaller image, if its bigger it would serve the big one.

Invest some time in learning the basics. Here are is a good source for you to learn more about srcset and sizes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: I have read this article. I did like you did but the images don't load. that's why I was asking. your solution doesn't load images. even the fallback image doesn't appear

Comment: @NicolasS Are you sure the paths to your images are right?
Does your image load if you just use the img tag? Like so: `<img src="../assets/img/splash.jpg">`? If not, the path to your image might be wrong. Thats hard to check from my side. Maybe try your src url without the two dots .. like this: <img src="/assets/img/splash.jpg">.

Comment: yes when I remove srcset and sizes everything works fine

Comment: @NicolasS I changed the sizes attribute in my answere above to a min-width setting. Please try that too. If this still won't work for you, I am afraid I can't help and there might be something else wrong. It seems to work for me.

Comment: I must specify that I'm using vuejs3. your code is working in a separate html file. but it seems VueJS is blocking.

Comment: it's working in production. strange bug. thanks anyway.